# CustomModalViewController with identifier in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller

I'm struggling with recreating a simple VC with a "present" button to modally transition to a 2nd custom VC that has a "close" button. Here is the Obj C code that I am trying to recreate in Swift:

```
- (IBAction)didClickOnPresent:(id)sender {

CustomModalViewController *modalVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customModal"];

modalVC.transitioningDelegate = self;

modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:modalVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Here my codes in Swift:

```
@IBAction func didClickOnPresent(sender: AnyObject) {

let modalVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("customModal") as! CustomModalViewController

modalVC.transitioningDelegate = self

modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom

self.navigationController?.presentViewController(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

For some reason, the modal was presented in the original VC instead of the 2nd VC. I checked the outlets, and identifiers. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Which controllers are supposed to be "original" / "2nd" in your code?

Comment: Sorry - I should have clarified - CustomModalViewController is the 2nd VC - which is in the code. Instead I get CustomVCTransitionViewController(the first VC) modally when I click the "present" button.

Answer (score 0):

You might be presenting from the wrong location. Try this instead:

```
self.presentViewController(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks Nate. Tried that before. Still got the same wrong view (the first VC).